# Elixir versioning public path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to use Elixir's version() method with my 'public' folder being public_html (instead of the default 'public' method).

I version my css file, which produces a build folder with the manifest inside public_html

```
elixir.config.cssOutput = 'public_html/css';
elixir.config.jsOutput = 'public_html/js';

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.styles([
        'vendor/normalize.css',
        'app.css'
    ], null, 'public_html/css');

    mix.version('public_html/css/all.css');

});
```

In my blade template I use

```
<link href="{{ elixir("css/all.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Problem is the elixir function searches in 'public/build' folder. How can I change this so it searches public_html folder?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5

Comment: Any way of not changing the public path in elixir config file?
I had to change it in /node_modules/laravel-elixir/ingredients/version.js before it would work!

Comment: `elixir()` uses `public_path()` so you need to override `path.public` as shown in the post I linked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to overwrite your publicDir folder in the `gulpfile.js` file, this points the `build` folder to the correct location which is used by elixir to determine the version hash.

```
elixir.config.publicDir = 'public_html';
```

After you did that you must overwrite your public_path in Laravel, the recommended way for Laravel 5 is to go to the `index.php` in your public folder:

Underneath

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Add

```
// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the solutions already but forgot to update this thread. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I added those lines but it does not seem to fix the problem, it still creates the public directory (instead of public_html)

Comment: You also need to add `elixir.config.publicPath = 'public_html';` as told by Lordcash

Comment: It seems the way to do it now is using the 2nd parameter to the php `elixir` function e.g. `elixir("app.js", "")` the default value is `build`. Setting it to the empty-string "moves it back" to `public`.

Comment: .. or `public_html` in this case.

Answer (score 5):

all you need do is this

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.publicDir = 'public_html';
elixir.config.publicPath = 'public_html';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in elixir() for changing the public path:

```
function elixir($file)
    {
        static $manifest = null;

        if (is_null($manifest))
        {
            $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path().'/build/rev-manifest.json'), true);
        }

        if (isset($manifest[$file]))
        {
            return '/build/'.$manifest[$file];
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("File {$file} not defined in asset manifest.");
    }
```

There are only few options. You can change public path by adding this to App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
          return base_path().'/public_html';
        });
    }
```

or you can create your own elixir function or a helper class

Example:

```
    function my_own_elixir($file,$path=public_path())
            {
                static $manifest = null;

                if (is_null($manifest))
                {
                    $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents($path.'/build/rev-manifest.json'), true);
                }

                if (isset($manifest[$file]))
                {
                    return '/build/'.$manifest[$file];
                }

                throw new InvalidArgumentException("File {$file} not defined in asset manifest.");
            }
```

Then you can use this later in view:

```
{{my_own_elixir('/css/all.css',$path='path to public_html')}}
```

Hopefully in future version of elixir this future will be included. :)

Comment: The path is not *hardcoded* it uses Laravels globally configured `public_path` which makes sense. And it can be easily overridden. No need to write your own function. (You also don't have to create a new service provider but can just use the AppServiceProvider for that)