# How to changed default path '/public' name in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

my server using cPanel. directory structure here

- laravel-project
- public_ftp
- public_html

  - public

    - index.php

I deployed on the server following this guy
https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-deploy-on-shared-hosting

everything well but my base path is "mydomain.com/public" 
I don't want to remove /public out from my path but to change it,
I want path like this "mydomain.com/noticed"

I using laravel version 5.3

Any Idea?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It was suggested](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5) to change the `index.php` in your public folder.

```
*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

> Now you dont need to change your public path when your public
>   directory has changed.
>
> Elixir has a hardcoded public path! Do not forget to set the changed
>   public path in the Elixir config.

I might add that you also need to make sure that your new public path have the same permission as the default one. You might also want to change the public path in the `config/filesystem.php`.

Comment: I use asset() to include source from js/css then all gone.
I following this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29716810/5071013
and change asset() to elixir() still don't work

Comment: Oh I have a ploblem on my XAMMP but production working still okay thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 5.6 add this code to bootstrap/app.php :

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../');
});
```

where **__DIR__.'/../'** is path to your public folder